# Creating a dynamic loop for cells.find function

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

Creating a macro that will take the `cell.value` (string) in worksheet A then go to Worksheet B, using the `cells.find` method locate the cell which match the string.

Example

```
SheetA.activecell.value = "Harry Potter"
set myvar = SheetA.activecell.value
sheetB.select
Cells.Find(What:=myvar, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ 
    MatchCase:=False).Select
```

Assuming the above syntax is correct, the cell in worksheet A which contains the string "Harry Potter" will be selected automatically.

This is where my problems come in. I want to do a loop through an entire column, executing the `Cells.Find` function for each cell in the column.

For example, `SheetA.cells(3 ,1)` contains "Harry Potter". Using the offset function on every completion of the loop, the cell containing the value to be found will be offset by 1 row.

So, in the next iteration of the loop, `Cells(4, 1)` in SheetA will contain the value to be used in the `cells.find` function.

Say, that value is the string "Iphone Charger".  Then, cells.find(what:=myvar (Basically myvar = "Iphone Charger") would be executed in worksheet B.

And so on down the column in worksheet A.

Secondly, I want to copy certain values in worksheets A.

Scenario:

```
If "Harry Potter" is found in sheetA then
     Do an `activecell.offset` function to copy some values in the same row as the cell in sheet A and 
     Copy those values to worksheet B using Copy destination
Else if "Harry Potter" can be found then 
     Jump to the next cell value.
End if 

Keep looping until worksheet B hits an empty cell, that is cells(X , 1).value = ""

Then the whole macro ends
```

Have been killing my brain cells to resolve this issue and would appreciate if any of you guys in this forum can help me.

Comment: It really looks like you have most of the components that you need to complete your macro...? The formatting that others have provided should help you construct it further. Have you created the initial macro yet? What error(s) is it giving you?

Comment: u have any sample codes to share?
Excel vba does'nt prompt any error, but the macro stops looping when it gets to this portion.

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=lookfor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False).Select

Comment: `Cells.Find` will search the entire sheet for the **first** instance of `lookfor`. To keep searching in a defined range, you'll need to use `FindNext`, a function that you'll be able to find several examples of how to use it here on SF. If you post more of your actual code, then we can help w/that as well

Comment: user2451335, do you need to find multiple instances of "Harry Potter" in sheetB, or are you just trying to loop through the column A values, finding one instance for each? Could you show us the actual code that you are using for the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `For Each` construct for your main loop on the cells with values to find in worksheet A. In pseudocode:

```
For each cell in column A of sheet A
    With the sheet B range to look in
        If cell value is "" 
            Exit the sub
        Else
            result = .find the cell value
            If the find is successful ("Not result is nothing") 
                Copy sheetA.cells(cell.row, <column of interest>) to sheet B
                Copy ... (cell.row,<another column of interest>) ...
            End the If
         End the if
    End the with 
Next cell
```

Note that this looks for only one instance of each value in column A of sheet A.

As Jaycal noted, you would need to use FindNext to find additional instances after the first one.

The basic idea is to find the first instance and save its address, then use a do loop with FindNext to look for more instances. The do loop keeps executing until FindNext finds a cell with the same address as the address you saved for the first instance that was found.

For a code example of this, see [this explananation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) or [this one](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112%3afind-method-in-excel-vba-find-multiple-occurrences-find-method-to-vlookup-find-date&catid=79&Itemid=475), among many others that can be found on the web.

Comment: chuff:
can u be more implicit abt the sentence:
with the sheet B range to look in, does'nt seem to quiet get it.

Comment: Actually, I mean it quite literally. Say the values in sheet B are in column B. You would code the With as `With Worksheets("B").Range("B:B")`. Then using `.Find(...)` would restrict the search to column B of sheet B.